# How to job file upload with Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I need to upload file to `S3` by queue the image then upload to `S3` using Livewire

My livewire Component :

```
class s3 extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate(['image' => 'image']);

        dispatch(new ImageUpload($this->image));

        return 'success';
    }
}
```

MY job class for queue working:

```
class ImageUpload implements ShouldQueue
{
    
    public $image;

    public function __construct($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/product_images/', $this->image, 'public');
    }
}
```

I got this error::

```
Exception
Serialization of 'Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile' is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass something that can be serialized.

One way off the top of my head (since it looks like you are storing the temporary file) would be to simply pass the temporary filename and path to your job which will handle the rest.

Something like this should work:

Your Livewire component:

```
class s3 extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate(['image' => 'image']);

        $image = [
            'name' => $this->image->getClientOriginalName(),
            'path' => $this->image->getRealPath(),
        ];

        dispatch(new ImageUpload($image));

        return 'success';
    }
}
```

Your Job class:

```
class ImageUpload implements ShouldQueue
{
    
    public $image;

    public function __construct($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/product_images/'.$this->image['name'], file_get_contents($this->image['path']), 'public');
    }
}
```

It's crude but should get you in the right direction.

Comment: BIG Thanks! How can I hash the name of image ?

Comment: I solve it with :  'name' => $this->image->hasName(),